# radio button is not staying checked after i click submit without filling the complete form, and select tag also not proper values

Tags: php, html

I am using this code for any user to submit there details and the radio buttons are supposed to be checked if user already has, and has submit the form without filling rest of the details, but its not staying checked. And also the select tag is not showing proper values, its just shows $location four times

```
<?php
$location = array("NY","MS","TX","CO");
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["place"]) || empty($_POST["password"])) {
$error=true;
}
else
{
header('location:index.php');
}
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
   <div style="padding:50px;text-align:center">
  <h2>Please fill all the Details</h2>
  </div>
    <?php } ?>
     <div style="padding:10px 0 0 500px">
     <h2>FORM</h2>
     <form action="form.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["name"])): echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]); endif ?>"><br><br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" <? if (isset($gender) && $gender=="M") echo "checked"; ?> Male<br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" <? if(isset($gender) && gender=="F" ) echo "checked"> Female<br><br>
     <select name="place">
     <option value=""></option>
     <?php foreach($location as $place) { if (isset($_POST["place"]) && $_POST["place"]==$location) echo '<option selected="selected" value="$location">$location</option>';
     else
     echo '<option value="$location">$location</option>'; }?>
     </select><br><br>
     <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
     </form>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are going to need to use either `ajax` or do a front end validation first with javascript, your php is server side each time it validates it will refresh the page.

Comment: for both..radio button and select tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code,

> ... the radio buttons are supposed to be checked if user already has, and has submit the form without filling rest of the details, but its not staying checked.

Look here,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" <? if (isset($gender) && $gender=="M") echo "checked"; ?> Male<br>
                                            ^^           ^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" <? if(isset($gender) && gender=="F" ) echo "checked"> Female<br><br>
                                            ^^          ^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^
```

The reason being `$gender` is undefined, and in one case you made it as constant but you never defined any constant in your code. Plus, your PHP tags are invalid. So change these two lines in the following way,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" <?php if (isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] == "M") echo "checked"; ?>> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" <?php if(isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender']=="F" ) echo "checked"; ?>> Female<br><br>
```

> And also the select tag is not showing proper values, its just shows $location four times

That's because you messed up your `foreach` loop, `$location` is an array, not a particular value, and in one case you even tried to check it's equality with a variable value, see the condition in the `if` block: `...$_POST["place"]==$location ...`

Change your `foreach` loop in the following way,

```
<?php 
    foreach($location as $place) { 
        if (isset($_POST["place"]) && $_POST["place"]==$place) 
            echo '<option selected="selected" value="' . $place . '">' . $place . '</option>';
        else
            echo '<option value="' . $place . '">' . $place . '</option>'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: select tag is working now thanks, but the radio button still not remains as checked

Comment: @GiteshSawariya I have updated my answer. Now it should work fine for you.

Comment: it did work thanks, can you please tell me hwo come it worked this way, and also can you please help me with radio buttons too, they does not remain checked, if i click on submit without completely fillingout the form

Comment: @GiteshSawariya That's the default behavior of form, you can't help it. Once you submit the form, values are sent to your server via `$_POST` superglobal. The same values will not be retained in `$_POST` if you hit the submit button again, rather new values will get passed to your server via `$_POST`, I hope you understood this point clearly.

Comment: yeah thanks a lot, still need help with radio buttons though

Comment: @GiteshSawariya It's working fine for me. What exactly you're trying to do? What happens when you submit the form?

Comment: @GiteshSawariya Glad I could help. You have been given 3 answers now. Please mark one of the answers as *accepted* answer. [How to accept answer on Stackoverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

You have used `foreach` but you have not concatenated the values in order to display in the select tag and now the values are been displayed and the `required attribute` can be added so that without selecting the SELECT tag the form will not be submitted.

Here is the modified code.

```
<?php
$location = array("NY","MS","TX","CO");
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["place"]) || empty($_POST["password"])) {
$error=true;
}
else
{
header('location:index.php');
}
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
   <div style="padding:50px;text-align:center">
  <h2>Please fill all the Details</h2>
  </div>
    <?php } ?>
     <div style="padding:10px 0 0 500px">
     <h2>FORM</h2>
     <form action="form.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["name"])): echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]); endif ?>"><br><br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" <? if (isset($gender) && $gender=="M") echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> Male<br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" <? if(isset($gender) && gender=="F" ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> Female<br><br>
     <select name="place" required>
     <option value=""></option>
     <?php foreach($location as $place) { 
        if (isset($_POST["place"]) && $_POST["place"]==$location) 
            echo '<option selected="selected" value="$location">'.$place.'</option>';
     else
     echo '<option value="$location">'.$place.'</option>'; }?>
     </select><br><br>
     <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
     </form>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is working thanks, can you help me with radio button too.

Comment: for radio button you have to use `$_POST['gender']` instead of `$gender` since $gender doesn't gove any meaning in that place.

Comment: In the top condition you are checking there also you have to use the same `$_POST['gender']` since then alone after posting the form you can check whether the data is empty or not. And as well as to display `checked="checked"` also you have to use the same method.

Comment: in both conditions?

Comment: Yes. In the top IF condition and as well as in the `<input type="">` condition too

Comment: @GiteshSawariya. if so you find my answer is useful you can upvote it or you can accept it since it might be useful for the other who face this same issue again. Thanks :)

Comment: i tried using $_POST["gender"] its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of using javascript to do a front end validation of an empty field, I will not code the entire form however this will get you pointed in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/F3hfD/77/

```
<h2>FORM</h2>
<form action="form.php" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" Male>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" Female>
  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
<script>
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: i want that if a user submit the form with only one checked radio box then it must remain checked after it alerts to fill the whole form

Comment: What part of the fiddle is not working the way you want?

Comment: can you help me wit radio buttons,  they does not remain checked, if i check one of them only and click on submit without completely fillingout the form

Comment: @GiteshSawariya the fiddle is not doing that?